# Test if a user already has a record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to test if a user already made a lesson for a course, and if so, take them to said lesson, otherwise, make them a new lesson. The lesson is a nested resource of the course, so I want to use :course_id to find if the user has a lesson created already, and if so take them to that lesson.

**My try**

```
    <% if current_user.lessons.course_id == (course)%>
        <td><%= link_to course.title, edit_lesson_path(:course_id) %></td>
<% end %>
```

(no else for now, want this to work first.)

Honestly any help would be great, and let me know if I should add anything :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `exists?` method. Here is the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class) for the method.

```
<% if current_user.lessons.exists?(course: course) %>
```

**Updated Solution**

@toddmetheny's solution will definitely be quicker as the user builds up lessons.

With that being said, I'd probably take his approach, but still use the `exists?` method:

```
<% if Lesson.exists?(user: current_user, course: course) %>
```

A quick benchmark, with 1000 iterations.

```
 # mine (first solution with a user with over 500 lessons)
 <Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc5b0ceaab8 @label="", @real=9.431750780000584, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.2999999999999998, @utime=7.6299999999999955, @total=7.929999999999995>

 # mine (updated solution) - Fastest
 <Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc5ab550d48 @label="", @real=8.289565541999764, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.3, @utime=6.7, @total=7.0>

 # toddmetheny
 <Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc5b09c5888 @label="", @real=9.237036614998942, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.30000000000000004, @utime=7.4, @total=7.7>
```

Comment: @Xavier, you can give toddmetheny that second upvote :) His answer led my to the updated solution

Comment: :D. One thing, I cant seem to figure out how to go to the lesson it found, would I just use a find by? something like: <%= link_to course.title, edit_lesson_path(Lesson.exists?(user: current_user, course: course)) %> gives me the error :undefined method exists? for true:TrueClass

Comment: `<%= link_to course.title, edit_lesson_path(Lesson.find_by(user: current_user, course: course)) %>`, however, you are going to want to refactor this. You really _don't_ want queries in your view. I would even refactor `Lesson.exists?(user: current_user, course: course)` to get this out of the view. Something like: `if current_user.has_lesson?(course)` then add that method in your user model.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Lesson.where(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: course.id).count > 0
```